# React Native @react-native-picker/picker not displaying options

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, dropdown, picker

I'm working on a React Native app and using @react-native-picker/picker for a dropdown menu. However, the picker is not displaying any options when clicked. Below is the relevant code snippet from my registration form component

```
const Registration = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    mentalHealthHistory: 'None',
    age: '',
    genderOptions: {
      Male: { selected: true, borderColor: 'white' },
      Female: { selected: false, borderColor: '#000' },
      Other: { selected: false, borderColor: '#000' },
    },
    therapyOption: 'Yes',
    contact: '',
  });

  const mentalHealthOptions = ['No Known History', 'Anxiety Disorders', 'Depression', 'Bipolar Disorder', 'Diagnosed PTSD', 'Schizophrenia', 'Substance Abuse', 'Eating Disorder', 'OCD', 'Personality Disorders', 'Self-harm', 'Other'];
  // ... rest of my code

  <Text style={styles.mainInputLabel}>Mental Health History</Text>
  <View style={styles.input}>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={user.mentalHealthHistory}
      onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
        setUser({ ...user, mentalHealthHistory: itemValue })
      }
    >
      {mentalHealthOptions.map((option, index) => (
        <Picker.Item key={index} label={option} value={option} />
      ))}
    </Picker>
  </View>

  // ...rest of my code

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//... rest of my styles
  input: {
    height: 54,
    marginBottom: 12,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderColor: "#4C6880",
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

});

export default Registration;
```

I've tried the following based on a suggestion to ensure the picker is visible:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={user.mentalHealthHistory}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => setUser({ ...user, mentalHealthHistory: itemValue })}
  style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 1000, elevation: 1000 }}
>
  {/* Picker Items */}
</Picker>
```

Despite this, the picker options still do not appear when the picker is tapped. I've checked that each Picker.Item has a valid label and value. Is there something I'm missing here? How can I get the Picker to properly display the options when interacted with?